# Rails set download link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The following link will list all the clients

```
localhost:3000/clients
```

And if i type the following link directly xls file will get downloaded

```
localhost:3000/clients.xls
```

This is my route

```
match 'client' => 'Clients#clients_new'
```

How do i provide a download link for this file

My view file name is `clients_new.html.erb` in `clients_controller` i have an action as `clients_new`

I tried

```
<p><%= link_to 'Download as Excel', newclients_path(:format => :xls) %></p>
```

It is throwing an error as

```
undefined method `newclients_path' for #<#<Class:0x999e02c>:0x9eeee3c>
```

**Rake route**

```
clients_newClients GET    /clients/newClients(.:format)          clients#newClients
```

Comment: Try client_new_path and make sure that you have updated routes.rb.

Comment: put your `rake routes` output

Comment: Tried now getting error as `undefined method `client_new_path' for`

Comment: @RajarshiDas added my rake route

Comment: `<%= link_to 'Download as Excel', newclients_path(:format => :xls) %>` to `<%= link_to 'Download as Excel', clients_newClients_path(:format => :xls) %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`Routes`:

```
match 'client' => 'Clients#clients_new'
```

`Link`:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Download as Excel', client_path(:format => :xls) %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your `rake routes`

```
<%= link_to 'Download as Excel', client_path(:format => :xls) %>
```

Comment: Am getting list this `The action 'newClients' could not be found for ClientsController`

Comment: can you please check your `rake routes out put given above`

Comment: Rake routes given above is correct same thing am getting. Is there any mistake in my `route.rb`

Comment: This works.. `<%= link_to 'Download as Excel', client_path(:format => :xls) %>`